# How do I sort combining 2 array in javascript (like c# (Array.sort() ))

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, linq, sorting

I have 2 arrays. Names in first array and indexes in second array. I ordered with C# (Array.sort() property).

Example : my array name is OrderedNames.

```
var names = OrderedName.SelectMany(x => x.Names)      // names array
var indexes = OrderedName.SelectMany(x => x.Indexes) // indexes array
Array.sort(indexes,names)                           // ordered names with indexes
```

I did this C# with LINQ.

I want to do the same thing with JavaScript.

So my Javascript code as the following(for example):

```
var names = Enumerable.From('$.OrderedNames').SelectMany('$.Names').ToArray();
var indexes = Enumerable.From('$.OrderedNames').SelectMany('$.Indexes').ToArray();
```

I can choose names and indexes. I want to merge two arrays and sorted.
I did this with C# Array.sort() but I didn't with Javascript.

Do you have any idea please?

Comment: I can tell you now your `JS` code isn't going to compile. You can't use `.NET` functionality (`LINQ`) directly from `JS` like that.

Comment: how can I do the same process with JavaScript I ask ? I know, I can't use .Net functionality directly from JS. @ext0

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/187/arrays/4206/sorting-arrays#t=201608031948491011675

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I think without `map.sort.map` you can do it like this too..

```js
var names = ['rhino', 'hippo', 'tiger', 'badger', 'crocodile'],
     keys = [4, 5, 3, 1, 2],
    clone = names.slice(),
   sorted = names.sort((a,b) => keys[clone.indexOf(a)]-keys[clone.indexOf(b)]);
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the names and keys together, sort them, and then return the sorted names like this

```
var names = ['two', 'three', 'one', 'four'];
var keys = [2, 3, 1, 4];

var sortedNames = names
                    .map((n, i) => { return { name: n, key: keys[i] }})
                    .sort((a, b) => a.key - b.key)
                    .map(n => n.name);

console.log(sortedNames); // ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']';
```